# Editing a string, Python

Tags: python, string

Disclaimer: very fresh to python. I have an assignment that asks me to calculate and print the frequency of every word in a file (along with the word) after stripping the punctuation and lowercasing all the words in the file. Right now I have the following combination of inputs for processing each line from the file:

```
import string

words = "Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Dave"
translation = str.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)
new = words.translate(translation)
lower = new.lower()
```

however this seems crude to me and I feel like I can accomplish my task with fewer function calls/less code. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Comment: I think this question would be more on-topic on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What do you mean "this seems crude"? This code doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeR: he just removed the `import string` which is needed for `string.punctuation`; otherwise it works fine.

Comment: If the code works but OP is seeking improvements, then Code Review would be a good place to post. However, perhaps a better descriptive title would make it better received there.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware there was such a thing as code review, so my apologies!

Comment: @jermenkoo The code doesn't work with or without the `import string`.

Comment: I think it's the grit at the end of the lines that's making it seem crude.

Comment: @JoeR: works for me using Python 3.5.0 at Win7 x64. In Python 2 you are going to get an `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'`

Comment: I'm running Python 3 on Mac OSX so that might be why- I've seen alot of different syntax for using 'translate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = "Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Dave"
words_lower = ' '.join([word.lower() for word in words.split(',')])
print (words_lower)


dave  laura  maddy  dave  laura  maddy  dave  laura  dave
```

Comment: The OP wants to calculate and print the frequency of every word in a file.

Comment: Yeah but that part I'm still figuring out and I wouldn't want you guys to do my assignment for me. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @galaxyan!

Comment: @DavidTamrazov I got that part ready. If you need help, I could post it

Comment: @galaxyan Much appreciated friend, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate the frequency of every word, you can try this one:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = "Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Dave"
>>> Counter([word.lower() for word in words.split(', ')])
Counter({'dave': 4, 'laura': 3, 'maddy': 2})
```

documentation for [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

---

a short alternative for the first answer:

```
>>> words = "Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Maddy, Dave, Laura, Dave"
>>> words.replace(',', ' ').lower()
'dave  laura  maddy  dave  laura  maddy  dave  laura  dave'
```

if you want to get rid of the punctuations(more than the ','):

```
>>> import re
>>> words = "Dave! Laura: Maddy; Dave, Laura? Maddy, Dave, Laura, Dave."
>>> re.sub(r'[!:;,?.]', '', words).lower()
'dave laura maddy dave laura maddy dave laura dave'
```